# CSS of pseudo-element affects parent element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I've set up a [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/MLThM/), where a CSS pseudo-element (::after) is displayed on mouse-hover on the given (parent-) element. Everything works fine so far, but the negative top-margin for the pseudo-element affects the parent instead of the generated element. (While the negative left-margin works as expected.)

Can anyone explain this behavior and/or know a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to be aware of is that when you use `::after`, the DOM looks like this:

```html
<div class="land" lang="de">[content of element]<after></after></div>
```

So, this behaves in exactly* the same way: *(use Chrome or Firefox)*
http://jsfiddle.net/MLThM/7/

And with some extraneous properties removed:
http://jsfiddle.net/MLThM/8/

The reason that the parent element moves is [collapsing margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).

One way to "fix" that is to add `overflow: hidden` to `.land`:
http://jsfiddle.net/MLThM/9/

And the fix applied to your original demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/MLThM/10/

<sub>* = let's forget about possible bugs in `::after` and `::before` for the moment, they aren't relevant to the current question.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You could always set your container div to `position:relative` and then the new content to `absolute`. This way you won't affect any of the margins on the containing div.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/MLThM/6/